# R Create symmetric matrix from uneven lengthed rows input file

Tags: r, matrix, file-io

I have a file with some values (25 as example here):

```
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
```

Which I want to read in a symmetric matrix or dataframe of equal row/column size, so 5*5 in this case. The first 5 elements will be the values in the first row in the matrix.

The matrix should look like:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 8.259e-03 5.264e-03 5.653e-03 3.301e-03 5.127e-05   
[2,] 8.259e-03 5.264e-03 5.653e-03 3.301e-03 5.127e-05
[3,] 8.259e-03 etc....
```

In my original .txt file, the matrix will be 86*86 and the amount of elements per row differ.

How would I go about reading this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no information in the question as to which matrix element in the result corresponds to which position in the input so we assume that the input when read row by row fills in a matrix in the order 1,1; 2,1; 3,1; ...; 5,5 .  Note that that does not give a symmetric matrix for the data in the question but we assume that your actual data is symmetric.

Now using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `scan` to read it in as a numeric vector and then shape it into a matrix.  Add the argument `byrow=TRUE` to `matrix` if you want the transpose instead.

```
vec <- scan("matrix.dat", quiet = TRUE)
n <- sqrt(length(vec))
m <- matrix(vec, n, n)
m
```

giving:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 8.259e-03 8.259e-03 8.259e-03 8.259e-03 8.259e-03
[2,] 5.264e-03 5.264e-03 5.264e-03 5.264e-03 5.264e-03
[3,] 5.653e-03 5.653e-03 5.653e-03 5.653e-03 5.653e-03
[4,] 3.301e-03 3.301e-03 3.301e-03 3.301e-03 3.301e-03
[5,] 5.127e-05 5.127e-05 5.127e-05 5.127e-05 5.127e-05
```

Noticing that there are only 5 unique values in the data if those were the values on the 5 diagonals then perhaps you want the following where vec and m are defined above.  This does give a symmatric matrix

```
matrix(unique(vec)[abs(row(m) - col(m)) + 1], 5, 5)
```

giving:

```
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 8.259e-03 0.005264 0.005653 0.003301 5.127e-05
[2,] 5.264e-03 0.008259 0.005264 0.005653 3.301e-03
[3,] 5.653e-03 0.005264 0.008259 0.005264 5.653e-03
[4,] 3.301e-03 0.005653 0.005264 0.008259 5.264e-03
[5,] 5.127e-05 0.003301 0.005653 0.005264 8.259e-03
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04
0.8259E-02  0.5264E-02
0.5653E-02  0.3301E-02
0.5127E-04"
cat(Lines, file = "matrix.dat")
```

Comment: I'll edit the question, but the order is normal reading from top left to right and then the next row, and that is the first row. So the first 5 elements are the ones in the first row, not column.

Comment: (1) The normal order in R is column by column and in any case (2) if the matrix were symmetric as claimed in the question and in the subject then it wouldn't matter, (3) the answer does already cover row by row when it states "Add the argument byrow=TRUE to matrix if you want the transpose instead."